# Generate BinarySecurityToken from .pfx certificate

Tags: java, ws-security

I'm receiving a request from the client and after some data masking, I forward the request to a web services. In order for the webservice to authorize me, I have to send in the < wsse:BinarySecurityToken > element. I have a .pfx certificate file and from this certificate, I need to generate the security token. The remaining part of the request is generated through SAAJ

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>my security token</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

How to generate "my security token" from .pfx file?

Demo code :

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\development\\certs\\cert.pfx");
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(inStream, "PASSWORD".toCharArray());
Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
String aliaz = "";
while(aliases.hasMoreElements()){
 aliaz = aliases.nextElement();
 if(ks.isKeyEntry(aliaz)){
      break;
 }
}
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(aliaz);
Base64 base64 = new Base64();
String token = base64.encodeToString(certificate.getSignature())
```

The token variable doesn't seem to match with the token generated from SOAPUI. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Can you try changing `ks.isKeyEntry` to `ks.isCertificateEntry`.

Comment: Thank you Abhinav for your prompt input. The token generated is the same as before and differs from SOAPUI generated one.

Comment: The token value seems to occur as the later part of SOAPUI generated token. For instance : if SOAPUI generated value is of length 1200, the token generated from java is the last 173 characters.

Comment: That seems correct. Is the webservice able to authenticate you or is it throwing an error? If error, what is it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to authenticate the request. Response error - <faultstring>*ASN.1 parse of PKIPath failed* (from client)</faultstring>

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
String token = base64.encodeToString(certificate.getSignature());
```

to

```
String token = base64.encodeToString(certificate.getEncoded());
```